# UI updating from different thread with delegates

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I have a class that manages the UI, which contains this method:

```
public void SetField(int field, int value)
```

I have a delegate declared:

```
public delegate void SetFieldDelegate(int field, int value);
```

On a buttonpress event, I call a computationally expensive method of another class, on a background thread. The UI doesn't freeze, the work is being done. On occasion, I want to update the UI though, I tried to use the delegate for this, to avoid cross-thread operations:

```
Gui.SetFieldDelegate TestDelegate = new Gui.SetFieldDelegate(gui.SetField);
```

In the heavy working method, I call:

```
TestDelegate.Invoke(field, value);
```

But it's still an invalid cross-thread opeartion. I'm sure it's something trivial, but I'm lost. Also, any suggestions are welcome, if there is a much easier way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `Invoke` on the *delegate*, which doesn't do anything about threads - it's just invoking it synchronously.

You need to call `Invoke` on an element of the UI, e.g.

```
form.Invoke(TestDelegate, value);
```

or `BeginInvoke` instead:

```
form.BeginInvoke(TestDelegate, value);
```

That's assuming you're using Windows Forms. If you're using WPF or Silverlight, you need to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` instead, e.g.

```
form.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(TestDelegate, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, () => { /* do some UI work - updating etc*/ });` for WPF or `this.BeginInvoke (new MethodInvoker(() => /* do some UI work - updating etc*/));` for Winforms.

Comment: At the moment this is over my head, but I will look into it, thanks!